Data transfer from HubSpot to Postgres using CloudQuery
I've fetched data from hubspot to postgres using cloudquery by creating 2 config file and running the sync. The config files are as:
hubspot.yml
kind: source
spec:
  name: "hubspot"
  path: cloudquery/hubspot
  registry: cloudquery
  version: "v4.4.3"
  destinations: ["postgresql"]  tables: ["*"]
  spec:
    app_token: "my_access_token"
    pagination:
      page_size: 1000
      max_retries: 5
    table_options:
      hubspot_crm_contacts:
        associations: ['contacts', 'deals', 'notes', 'emails', 'tasks', 'meetings', 'calls', 'company']
      hubspot_crm_companies:
        associations: ['contacts', 'deals', 'notes', 'emails', 'tasks', 'meetings', 'calls', 'company']
      hubspot_crm_deals:
        associations: ['contacts', 'deals', 'notes', 'emails', 'tasks', 'meetings', 'calls', 'company']

postgres.yml
kind: destination
spec:
  name: "postgresql"
  path: "cloudquery/postgresql"
  registry: "cloudquery"
  version: "v8.5.1"
  write_mode: "overwrite-delete-stale"
  spec:
    connection_string: "postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/dbsync?sslmode=disable"

That worked and i get data on postgres.
From there let's take a table 'hubspot_crm_contacts'. There are 2 column in jsonb format one is properties wihch is as:
example from ''
{
  "email": "elon@gmail.com",
  "lastname": "Musk",
  "firstname": "Elon",
  "createdate": "2024-08-05T09:06:00.072Z",
  "hs_object_id": "28109002461",
  "lastmodifieddate": "2024-08-05T11:00:14.253Z"
}

and another is associations which is as:
{
  "companies": {
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "13176491214",
        "type": "contact_to_company"
      },
      {
        "id": "13176491214",
        "type": "contact_to_company_unlabeled"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Can't even figure out why same company is fetched twice.
for now a contact is associated with company only but later on it can be associated with all these:
['contacts', 'deals', 'notes', 'emails', 'tasks', 'meetings', 'calls', 'company']

Problem:
The issues is the query structure gets very complex to fetch contact along with associated data and similar for other cases. I'm doing this to fetch contact with associated companies:
WITH company_data AS (
    SELECT 
        c.id AS contact_id,
        c.properties ->> 'firstname' AS first_name,
        c.properties ->> 'lastname' AS last_name,
        c.properties ->> 'email' AS email,
        jsonb_array_elements(c.associations -> 'companies' -> 'results') AS company_json
    FROM 
        hubspot_crm_contacts c
)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON (contact_id, company_id) 
    cd.contact_id,
    cd.first_name,
    cd.last_name,
    cd.email,
    cmp.id AS company_id,
    cmp.properties ->> 'name' AS company_name,
    cmp.properties ->> 'domain' AS company_domain
FROM 
    company_data cd
LEFT JOIN 
    hubspot_crm_companies cmp 
    ON (cd.company_json ->> 'id') = cmp.id
ORDER BY 
    contact_id, company_id, cd.company_json ->> 'type' DESC;
but what if i had to fetched other associations too ?

So i need help managing this data.
I got no clues what to do.
Can i transform the data before storing in postgres ?
Help needed.
I want to store data in either suitable format or any other ways to simplify the SQL queries to fetch data as querying on JSONB is very complex for me.
